# Are peer-reviewed scientific journals subject to FOIA?

Tags: united-states

Are peer-reviewed scientific journals subject to the Freedom of Information Act?  I found this somewhat helpful page: [Open Meeting Laws and Non-Profit Organizations](http://www.dmlp.org/forum/newsgathering-law/open-meeting-laws-and-non-profit-organizations) (Digital Media Law Project).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  Freedom of information laws are about government information.  Peer reviewed journals are not government institutions.

Comment: What about open meeting laws?  They vary from state to state but I think there's a pattern.

Comment: What about them?  Do you have a question about the material you linked to?  What are you trying to get at?

Comment: For example, suppose I want to know if a particular article's author has received funding from a pharmaceutical company (and the author is writing about a drug trial and the drug is made by that company)?

Comment: @aparente001 would the journal even know how the author's research was funded?

Comment: Okay, back to the drawing board.  Thank you.

Comment: @aparente001 That wasn't a rhetorical question. I don't know much about how peer-reviewed journals work; it's possible that they *are* supposed to know these things.